# If I have a series of random variables $X_t$ where $p(X_n |X_{n-1}, ..., X_{1}) = f(X_n)$, how to show $X_n$ depends only on $X_{n+1}$ and $X_{n-1}$?

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

If I have a series of random variables $X_t$, $t\geq1$ where $p(X_n |X_{n-1}, ..., X_{1}) = f(X_{n-1})$ for some probability function $f$, how can I show that the distribution of $X_n$ given ALL the series of random variables depends only on $X_{n+1}$ and $X_{n-1}$? That is, how can I show that $p(X_n | X_{1},...)$ is some function of $X_{n+1}$ and $X_{n-1}$? I have tried to do conditioning but it appears that I am always left with an infinite sequence, of which I am not sure what to do with. Would you have any hints as to what I can do? Thanks!

Comment: As stated, this doesn't make any sense.  You've said that the probability distribution of $X_n$ is a function of $X_n$ (which is, at that point, an unknown quantity).  And you've expressed things in terms of conditioning $X_n$ on the values of $X_{n-1},\ldots,X_1$ on the other side... so where is a dependence on the future (that is, $X_{n+1}$) coming from?  

There are either typos here, or I'm severely missing something.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I corrected it, it should say that the probability distribution of $X_n$ is a function of $X_{n-1}$.

Comment: That still doesn't explain the appearance of $X_{n+1}$.